# Find two objects with the same type in mongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an arrays of objects as below in my data:

```
traits = [{type: 'Language' , val: 'English'} , {type: 'Age' , val: 37} , {type: 'Language' , val: 'Spanish'}]
```

I need to find out if each of the traits arrays I have in my documents, have at least two 'Language' types. if they do update the val to 'MultiLang'.

What is the best way to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is your expected result, but if I understand you correctly, you can use update with pipeline:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {$set: {
      language: {$filter: {
          input: "$traits",
          cond: {$eq: ["$$this.type", "Language"]}
      }},
      traits: {$filter: {
          input: "$traits",
          cond: {$ne: ["$$this.type", "Language"]}
      }}
  }},
  {$set: {
      language: {
        type: "Language",
        val: {$cond: [
            {$gt: [{$size: "$language"}, 1]},
            "MultiLang",
            {$first: "$language.val"}
        ]}
      }
  }},
  {$set: {
      traits: {$concatArrays: [
          "$traits",
          [{$first: "$language"}]
      ]},
      language: "$$REMOVE"
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iU9fl8XrVl6)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this was exactly my expected result, except your answer creates a new language field instead of updating the data I had in the traits array. Any way I can fix that?

Comment: It created a new language array in the root of my document and added the type and text inside that

Comment: It also duplicated some of the language objects

Comment: Can you provide a playground example to show this?

Comment: I cannot re-create it on playground for some reason. On playground your query works fine. Even though my data has the same structure

Comment: In order to help you I need to see the problem. From the query itself (if executed as I wrote it) and the playground test, I can't see a way it will duplicate objects or create new arrays...

Comment: I understand.I'll set this as the correct answer. Gotta find out why it is not working on my db